# Error: cannot open source file #include<libcec/cec.h> in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include

I am trying to use `libcec` in Visual Studio 2012. I am done with all process of setting it up. However when I use

```
# include<libcec/cec.h>
```

it gives an error cannot open source file. What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the path of this library into VC++ include directory:

[image]

Otherwise, find the exact path of this header (`cec.h`), and others, and put full path in `#include` statement.